# Calculating the sum with Power Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

We're stuck on trying to evaluate the sum of this function using the power series, if you guys could provide some tips to continue through the process thank you.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-\pi^n}{4^n(2n-1)}$$
We tried moving the 4 up and factoring giving us
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\frac{-\pi}{4}^n}{(2n-1)}$$ But still nothing to move on from, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In essence, consider the powerseries with $x$ where $x$ has been replaced by $\pi/4$.

Comment: Ok done. $$-1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(2n-1)}$$ But I'm still not seeing how to move on from this.

Comment: the negative can go up front, we don't need that here

Comment: Hint: Start with geometric series, replace $x$ by $x^2$, then divide both sides by $x^2$ and integrate. See Ross' answer to finish it. (When integrating, don't forget to assume a constant)

Answer (score 2):

Can you sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n-2}$?  Integrate it term by term and you get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$ Now multiply by $x$, set $x=\frac {\sqrt \pi}2$, and negate it.

Answer (score 1):

For $\lvert x \rvert \lt 1,$ we have $$\tanh^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}.$$

So you can write your sum as

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-\pi^n}{4^n(2n-1)}&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\sqrt{\pi}/2)^{2n}}{2n-1}
\\&=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\sqrt{\pi}/2)^{2n-1}}{2n-1}
\\&=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right).
\end{align}